# Problems getting Arduino GSM lib to work with Nucleo L073RZ

Tags: arduino, hardware, stm32, uart, nucleo

I'm trying to use the [Adafruit Fona Mini GSM](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module/overview) together with the [Nucleo L073RZ](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l073rz.html). There exists a [library for the GSM module](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module/arduino-test), but it's for arduino. I've setup the board manager url to make use of the link in this repository: https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/README.md to add support for the MCU I'm using.

It's not possible to use SoftwareSerial together with this MCU it seems like. The library disappears when the card is selected. The GSM library supports HardwareSerial by uncommenting some lines though, which I've done. Unfortunately the MCU is unable to communicate with the GSM module.

Tera Term image

[image]

This is how everything is connected.

Hardware image

[image]

In case it's not apparent by the picture, this is how the GSM module connects to the MCU.

Vio connects to 5V
GND connects to GND
RX connects to TX/D1
TX connects to RX/D0

This is the only code modification I've made in the FONATest example, just to use hardware serial instead of software serial.

```
// We default to using software serial. If you want to use hardware serial
// (because softserial isnt supported) comment out the following three 
lines 
// and uncomment the HardwareSerial line
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//SoftwareSerial fonaSS = SoftwareSerial(FONA_TX, FONA_RX);
//SoftwareSerial *fonaSerial = &fonaSS;

// Hardware serial is also possible!
HardwareSerial *fonaSerial = &Serial1;
```

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope?  Seeing whether any data is actually going into or out of the GSM module is *very* useful in cases like this.  A logic probe or logic analyzer would also work.  (My wild guess: `Serial1` may not be the STM serial port that's actually connected to the Arduino TX/RX pins.)

Comment: I'm working with Erik Befwe on this project and helped write this question. I wanted to reply to you jasonharper, but I need 50 rep to do so, so I guess I will post here instead. We are both not very experienced with hardware but we had the same thoughts as you did. We would like to somehow find and possibly change which pins are used for tx/rx, but haven't been able to find a way to do so. We also thought about checking all the pins using an oscilloscope but we wont have access to one until Monday now.

Comment: Write your own communcation. Do not use arduino bloatware